# Is 认 related to 人?

Tags: simplified-characters, glyph-origin, traditional-vs-simplified

The verb "to know" 认 (rèn) is the simplified form of 認 (言 → 讠 and 忍 → 人). I'm not very familiar with the history behind simplifying characters, but I'm aware many characters generally have a semantic and phonetic component.

In simplifying this character, was 人 (rén) intentionally chosen to maintain a phonetic component,* or is this just coincidence?

---

* as an analogue to the original phonetic meaning of 忍 (rěn)

Comment: Not quite the case, the simplification actually was done to reduce the number of strokes in the traditional character, 認. During the process of the simplification, 忍 (rěn) in 認, was replaced with another same sounding component, 人 (rén) in this case, to omit the number of strokes needed to write the character. This has actually happened a few times when traditional characters get simplified. (e.g. 鍾 -> 钟, 鄰 -> 邻, 礬 -> 矾)

Comment: @prismcool ah sorry I phrased that poorly - I'm aware the point of simplification is to make the characters simpler to write/remember, I meant was this specific simplification chosen for phonetic reasons (as opposed to any other potential simplified character). I'll edit the q to be clearer!

Comment: @月-- It is quite obvious the case as they didn't simplify 忍 to 刃 or 心 but chose 人 instead.